# How to score each kmeans clusters using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

How can I score each kmeans clusters separately using sklearn?
My code is like below and every evaluation metrics I see ends up in one score for all the clusters but I need to evaluate each clusters separately.

```
model = MiniBatchKMeans(init ='k-means++', n_clusters = 2, 
                        batch_size = 200, max_no_improvement = 10, verbose = 0) 
model.fit(X)
labels = model.labels_
print(metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels, metric='euclidean'))
```

And if anyone has a better idea for my problem this is the actual problem I want to solve:

I want to cluster very large dataset of tf-idf vectors (very sparse vectors) and I dont know the true labels or even the number of clusters. So I want to do a hierarchical clustering using kmeans and at each step use kmeans (with k=2) to get better clusters and keep doing it until the evaluation metrics get worse. I saw other clustering algorithms like Agglomerativeclustering or Optics but they dont work with sparse datasets, And there is not enough memory to increase k and try upper numbers with kmeans. So any better ideas?

Comment: So, you want to find out the optimal number of clusters? Have you tried Elbow method?

Comment: @GavinKwon the problem is I cant actually increase the number of clusters to use the Elbow method.

Comment: Why would scoring the clusters separately help you identify the optimal # of clusters?

Comment: You shouldn’t use kmeans if you don’t have enough memory and can only use a fixed size k. The whole point of kmeans is to find the ideal k not be constrained due to memory. You also mentioned the vectors are sparse which makes me wonder why you have such little memory - I would suggest using tSNE to reduce the dimensionality while preserving structure but if the vectors are sparse already and you have little memory then it might not work either. May be worth a try

Comment: If that's the case, could you try fit_predict(X), instead of fit(X)? It will return the label then use that label for silhouette_score.

Comment: @AriK yes my vectors are sparse. but for example when I try k = 10000 I have this error : Unable to allocate 53.3 GiB for an array with shape (10000, 715312) and data type float64. and my dataset is 3.5M tweets so I guess the actual k is even more than this.

Comment: @GavinKwon still got same error for large k

Comment: Try a K between 10,000 and 2 lol... you have a wide range there where you may not have a memory error. Do like k=10,9,8 etc